# Apply the natural logarithm fractional number of times

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Let `f_n(x)` be the recursive function that adds `1` to `x` and takes the natural logarithm, `n` number of times:

```
f_n(x) = log(1 + log(1 + log(...log(1 + x)))...)
```

Recursive definition:

```
f_n(x) = x                 , for n  = 0
f_n(x) = log(1 + f_n-1(x)) , for n != 0
```

In example:

```
f_0(x) = x
f_1(x) = log(1 + x)
f_2(x) = log(1 + log(1 + x))
f_3(x) = log(1 + log(1 + log(1 + x)))
```

**Question**:
Is there a function that generalizes `f_n(x)` for fractional n? If not, is there a good approximation?

Comment: A one-liner for octave/matlab: `x=[0:0.001:1];plot(x,x,x,log(1+log(1+log(1+log(1+x)))),x,log(1+x),x,log(1+log(1+x)),x,log(1+log(1+log(1+x))))`

Comment: To be clear about what it would mean to generalize, let's write $f_n(x)=F(n,x)$. The defining property for iterated compositions (even for a different $f_1$) is $F(a, F(b,x))=F(a+b, x)$.  If you could inductively find $F(1/2^n,x)$, the defining property would let you define $F$ for dyadic rational numbers, and continuity would define it for everything else. On the other hand, if you can't make the inductive definition, that tells you that such a function does not exist.

Comment: When programming this recursion, use `log1p(x)`, if available, instead of `log(1+x)` for greater precision for very small 'x'.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series of this iteration starts as
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=x -\tfrac{1}{2}\,x^2 +\tfrac{1}{3}\,x^3 -\tfrac{1}{4}\,x^4 
        +\tfrac{1}{5}\,x^5 -\tfrac{1}{6}\,x^6 +\tfrac{1}{7}\,x^7 
        -\tfrac{1}{8}\,x^8 +\tfrac{1}{9}\,x^9 
\\
f_2(x)&=x -x^{2} +\tfrac{7}{6}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{35}{24}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{19}{10}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{917}{360}\,x^{6} 
        +\tfrac{8791}{2520}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{97933}{20160}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{310979}{45360}\,x^{9}
\\
f_3(x)&=x -\tfrac{3}{2}\,x^{2} +\tfrac{5}{2}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{35}{8}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{947}{120}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{1309}{90}\,x^{6} 
        +\tfrac{45779}{1680}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{417121}{8064}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{187591}{1890}\,x^{9}
\\
f_4(x)&=x -\tfrac{2}{1}\,x^{2} +\tfrac{13}{3}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{39}{4}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{337}{15}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{37919}{720}\,x^{6} 
        +\tfrac{630521}{5040}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{2018519}{6720}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{88017067}{120960}\,x^{9} 
\\
f_5(x)&=x -\tfrac{5}{2}\,x^{2} +\tfrac{20}{3}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{55}{3}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{617}{12}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{7021}{48}\,x^{6} 
        +\tfrac{70687}{168}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{4924247}{4032}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{37032377}{10368}\,x^{9}
\\
f_6(x)&=x -\tfrac{3}{1}\,x^{2} +\tfrac{19}{2}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{247}{8}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{3061}{30}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{49151}{144}\,x^{6} 
        +\tfrac{387325}{336}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{3954955}{1008}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{325190167}{24192}\,x^{9}
\\
f_7(x)&=x -\tfrac{7}{2}\,x^{2} +\tfrac{77}{6}\,x^{3} -\tfrac{385}{8}\,x^{4} 
        +\tfrac{21973}{120}\,x^{5} -\tfrac{506989}{720}\,x^{6}
        +\tfrac{1965991}{720}\,x^{7} -\tfrac{6823077}{640}\,x^{8} 
        +\tfrac{723432287}{17280}\,x^{9}
\end{align}
so apparently
$$
f_n(x)=x-\tfrac{n}2 x^2+\tfrac{n(3n+1)}{12}x^2-\tfrac{n(2n+1)(3n+1)}{48}+...
$$

Comment: I really appreciate this answer: I think it's useful to remember that in mathematics, insights can come not just from deep understanding of definitions and their consequences, but also from getting your hands a little messy and experimenting with small examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to defining the value of $F ( y, x )$ for $y = a/b$, where $a < b$.

For every given fractional $a_1 / b_1$ you set $a_1 / b_1 = z + a/b$ ,where $a < b$. $F ( z, x )$ is given ($z$ is natural) so what remains is to define the value of $F( a/b, x )$.

In my opinion when $a < b, F ( a/b, x )$ ought to be between $x$ and $\log (1+x)$.

You can set it to be the weighted average for instance:
$$
    F ( \frac{a}{b}, x ) = \frac{ax + b \log (1+x)}{(α+β)}
$$